# CSS-Vertical alignment attribute doesn't work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following css and html code. For a list of vertical menu items.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="" width="15%" nowrap="">   
            <div id="LeftOne">
            <ul id="LeftTwo">
              <li>
             </li>
            </ul>       
           </div>
           </td>
           <td valign="top" width="70%" >    
           </td>
           <td valign="" width="15%" nowrap="">  </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>


ul#LeftTwo {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin: 35px 0px 12px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid 
    #C8C8C8;
}

#LeftOne {
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    min-height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

td
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
background: 
transparent;
}
```

When I used `vertical-align: top;` then the list came to the very top. But I need to know why it is happening? Is there any issues using `vertical-align:top !ie;` to hack ie?

[image: Please find the image]

Comment: may be this link will help u http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: @ F. Calderan: I haven't used any doctype.

Answer (score 0):

Hey now you can define `valign top` in **your first** `td` as like this

```
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="15%" nowrap="">   
            <div id="LeftOne">
            <ul id="LeftTwo">
              <li>
             </li>
            </ul>       
           </div>
           </td>
           <td valign="top" width="70%" >    
           </td>
           <td valign="" width="15%" nowrap="">  </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: valign is a depreciated attribute. Use vertical-align instead.